# Notice: Undefined index: value in noverwrite_civicrm_buildForm()

Tags: extension

I have the no overwrite extension installed latest version.
Civi 5.2.2 
I get the message on bringing up a profile form

Answer (score 1):

the message gives a notice, that is a low level message that does not signify a "real" problem, rather that the program should do an additional check to make sure it meets the syntax rules.

So although the notice can be fixed, I would recommend you log the issue on the actual extension repository (https://github.com/TechToThePeople/noverwrite/issues) and rest assured that the notice does not present an urgent problem that needs fixing immediately.

Comment: logged issue on github